# What is the computational complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What is the computational complexity of the following algorithm?

```
for(int i = n; i = 1; i = i / 2) {
    for(int j = 1; j < n; j = j * 2) {
        System.out.println("i="+i+", j="+j);
    }
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Then [edit] your question to include your current solution and explain why it should be the right complexity for this algorithm.

Comment: Note also that Stack Overflow's focus is on narrow questions about *specific problems that you actually face* during the *practice of programming*. There's a separate [cs.se] site in the Stack Exchange network for questions that are about theory rather than practice.

Comment: But it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is O(log(n)), since every step, I is cut in half, so to increase the number of steps the loop takes by one, you'd have to *double* i.
The inner loop is also O(log(n)), for a similar reason. 
Thus, the overall complexity is O(log^2(n))